# Modifying a variable in a module imported using from ... import *

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Consider the following code:

```
#main.py
From toolsmodule import *
database = "foo"

#toolsmodule
database = "mydatabase"
```

As it seems, this creates one variable in each module with different content. How can I modify the variable inside toolsmodule from main? The following does not work:

```
toolsmodule.database = "foo"
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sounds like yet another of the multitude of good reasons not to use `from toolsmodule import *`.

If you just do `import toolsmodule`, then you can do `toolsmodule.database = 'foo'`, and everything is wonderful.

Comment: I know of this, but I use these variables a lot, I have long module names, and I would like to avoid the extra typing.

Comment: So make module names short: `import longmodulename as sname`. Now `sname` will refer to `longmodulename`.

Comment: If you don't want to type `toolsmodule` everytime, you can do the following: `import toolsmodule as tm`. This way you keep your namespace sane and save typing.

Comment: And if you really want to spam your main namespace with toolsmodule.*, just use both techniques together: `import toolsmodule; from toolsmodule import *`.

Answer (score 6):

Pythons variable names are just labels on variables. When you `import *` all those labels are local and when you then set the database, you just replace the local variable, not the one in toolsmodule. Hence, do this:

toolsmodule.py:

```
database = "original"

def printdatabase():
   print "Database is", database
```

And then run:

```
import toolsmodule
toolsmodule.database = "newdatabase"
toolsmodule.printdatabase()
```

The output is

```
Database is newdatabase
```

Note that if you then from ANOTHER module ALSO did an `import *` the change is not reflected.

In short: NEVER use `from x import *`. I don't know why all newbies persist in doing this despite all documentation I know of says that it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do it like that:

```
import toolsmodule
toolsmodule.database = "foo"
from toolsmodule import *  #bad idea, but let's say you have to..
print database #outputs foo
```

Comment: When I tried this, I believe I ended up not being able to modify the variable from inside toolsmodule anymore. This needs to be verified.