# Get variable from file which is importing my function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I have 2 files:

**`Main.py`**

```
from test import test
def main():
    sol = 'hello'
    if test() == sol:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

**`test.py`**

```
def test():
    return 'hello'
```

Is there a way to access the **sol** variable in my test function which is in another file? I'd like to do something like this:

```
def test():
    return sol
```

This way it's always the same as the variable in Main.py. I tried a solution which is mentioned on [Python extract variables from an imported file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632067/python-extract-variables-from-an-imported-file) but it didn't work for me. Thank you for any help

Edit: I'd like to do it without changing the Main.py file

Comment: Then, your output will always be `Yes`, what's the meaning of your code?

Comment: @lagom It's just a simple code to show my issue and what i'd like to do. I am curious if something like this is possible

Comment: Pass the variable to the function as a parameter? `def test(sol): return sol`

Comment: @TyloBedo would it be possible without changing the Main.py ?

Comment: You would need to pass the variable to test in Main.py `if test(sol) == sol:`. What are you actually trying to accomplish? I think you’re probably going about it in the wrong way.

Comment: @TyloBedo I'd like to make Main.py falsely print `Yes`

Answer (score 2):

Since `sol` isn't defined in the function you will need to declare it as a global function so it can be used in the function. Change `test.py`to the following...

```
test():
    global sol
    return sol
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am very sorry, i forgot to mention the sol variable is in a function too. Would it be possible to access it like this?

Answer (score 2):

If sol is a constant (i.e. a variable which will not change during the course of the program), then you can put it into a separate file, say var.py, and import it into both main.py and test.py:

```
from var import sol
```

BUT what you will be importing is a copy of the variable with the value it had at the time it was imported - any subsequent reassignments will not update the value of sol in test.py and main.py. Because a string is immutable, when you reassign a value to it what you are actually doing is you are reusing the variable name for a new entity.

What you need to do is have your variable in a mutable structure, such as a list or a class, so your var.py will look like this:

```
class v(object):
    sol = 'Hello'
```

and then in main.py and test.py you can refer to sol using:

```
from var import v
print(v.sol)
```

This way, any changes to v.sol will be correctly reflected anywhere class v is imported. A bit cumbersome, but that's how it is in Python.

Comment: So there isn't really a way to do it without touching the main.py and creating a new file?

Comment: The cleanest way would be to put the shared variable in a separate file, which can be imported by all files which need access to the variable (via a mutable structure such as a class, list etc.) If you do not want to do that, you can put the class **v** in **test.py**, and then import it in **main.py** together with your **test** function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inspect` module to get the `sol` variable from `main` function without change anything of `main.py`. Of course, you need to call `main` function.

**Main.py:**

```
from test import test
def main():
    sol = 'hello'
    if test() == sol:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')

main()
```

**test.py:**

```
import inspect

def test():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    sol_from_main = 'default'
    try:
        sol_from_main = frame.f_back.f_locals['sol'] # line A
    except:
        print('No sol found')
    print(sol_from_main)  # this print 'hello'
    return sol_from_main
```

**Output:**

> hello
>
> Yes

**Explanation:**

From the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html), we can see next:

> frame
>
> f_back   | next outer frame object (this frame’s caller)
>
> f_locals | local namespace seen by this frame

So `line A` get the caller of current function, that is `main function`, and use `f_locals` to get all local variables of `main function`, so it can get the `sol` value from `main`. FYI in case you still need it.