# How can I permanently alter the values within a module from a separate script

Tags: python

I have a module `english.py` which contains a dictionary `monograms`.  The value associated with each key is of type `str` and I would like to permanently change the type of the value associated with each key to `int` from a separate script. 
I have tried to mimic the response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758562/modifying-a-variable-in-a-module-imported-using-from-import) with the following:

```
import english
english.monograms['the'] = int(english.monograms['the'])
print(type(english.monograms['the']))
```

yielding the expected: `<class 'int'>`

However, when I rerun the code with the 2nd line commented out:

```
import english
#english.monograms['the'] = int(english.monograms['the'])
print(type(english.monograms['the']))
```

I recieve `<class 'str'>`

How can I make this change permanant without a complicated function that would read, parse and re-write the module?

Comment: Not possible. Every script starts fresh, just reading the code you tell it to. You have to modify the `english.py` source file.

Comment: You could store your data somewhere else

Comment: This *really* should be stored out-of-band from code. Putting mutable data in-line with code is not just uncommon practice -- it creates security vulnerabilities, since it requires that your code (which, when read, can perform completely arbitrary operations of its choice) be writable. Common practice would be to create a file in the user's home directory (`~/monograms.json` or such), and read that file back.